# Should we ignore constant k in O(nk)?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, asymptotic-complexity

Was reading CLRS when I encountered this:
[image]
[image]

Why do we not ignore the constant k in the big o equations in a. , b. and c.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you aren't considering the run time of a single algorithm, but of a *family* of algorithms parameterized by `k`. Considering `k` lets you compare the difference between sorting `n/n == 1` list and `n/2` 2-element lists. Somewhere in the middle, there is a value of `k` that you want to compute for part (c) so that Θ(nk + n lg(n/k)) and Θ(n lg n) are equal.

Going into more detail, insertion sort is O(n^2) because (roughly speaking) in the worst case, any single insertion could take O(n) time. However, if the sublists have a fixed length k, then you know the insertion step is O(1), independent of how many lists you are sorting. (That is, the bottleneck is no longer in the insertion step, but the merge phase.)

Answer (score 1):

K is not a constant when you compare different algorithms with different values of k.